# Jenkins configuration for source code management throws an error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I entered the subversion URL in the source code management section. I am 100% sure that the URL is correct and I have entered it successfully so many times before. But now all of a sudden, jenkins throws

> "Status code 500 Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.setAuthenticationStorageOptions(Lorg/tmatesoft/svn/core/internal/wc/ISVNAuthenticationStorageOptions;)V
>   Stacktrace:javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: "

Why is this happening? How to solve this?

p.s: You can do a Ctrl++ on the browser to view the image

[image]

Comment: Did it all the sudden stop working or is it a new url? Make sure your system's JDK didn't change also through some automated upgrade.

Comment: Could you have incompatible/duplicate svnkit libraries as [this issue](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Subversion-issues-after-restoring-Jenkins-backup-td4185183.html) talks about?

Comment: Did you upgrade jenkins lately?

Comment: I tried moving Jenkins to new jenkins_home. But that did not work. SO I flipped back to old jenkins_home and I noticed this error after that. It used to work fine before.

Comment: @Raghuram Thanks for the tip. I deleted and re-installed the plugin and it started working :-)